# how to filter data in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter the data according to several criteria, and based on these criteria, the record record number 7 (M08) should not appear because the "NewSiteID" column is not null and does not belong to the number 6, but the problem is that this record appears even though I used the conditions that appear in the query.

````
       tbMachines.MachIsTransfered, tbMachines.NewSiteID
FROM tbMachines
WHERE BranchID = 6 AND MachIsTransfered = 0
      OR      BranchID = 6 AND MachIsBorrowed = 1
      OR      BranchID = 6 AND MachIsloaning = 1
      AND NewSiteID = 6 OR NewSiteID = '' ```

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhkUP.png
````

Comment: Most people here want table data as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Is very possible that the record is matched by any of the OR conditions. Try to use parenthesis to set the priorities between AND and OR clauses

Comment: I am sorry because I can't make a table to Explain the problem more precisely

Comment: Sample table and expected result would make things much clearer - [mcve].

Comment: Each criteria should be inside parenthesis and OR should be between closed in parenthesis statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis around your conditions. In this case it can also be simplified quite a bit. If I understand what you are trying to do it could be something like this.

```
WHERE BranchID = 6 
    AND 
    (
        MachIsTransfered = 0
        OR
        MachIsBorrowed = 1
        OR 
        MachIsloaning = 1
    )
    AND NewSiteID in (6, '')
```

Comment: Sean Lange: the result of your answer is is only two records, As for the correct result should be 7 records, meaning that the only row that should be excluded is row number 7 in the picture (M08).

Comment: I have no data to work with. I am NOT going to take your picture and type everything out so I have sample data. And even if I did type that out there is data in your where predicates that are not in the image. I took a shot in the dark based on your query you posted.

Comment: Oh maybe the NULL in NewSiteID is the issue. NULL is not the same thing as an empty string. You would need to use NewSiteID IS NULL